# Setting (above/under) priority order of layer in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, layers, order

When I add a layer in leaflet it stays automatically above all layers I want layers to be ordered wich one stays above the other in way that last added layer will not stays above and hide the other layers that may I have interaction with them (mouse :click,out,move...).
here my example [order layers leaflet](http://plnkr.co/edit/GtfUFaWBIPUXYc9EHbC5)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can work with `layer.bringToFront()`, `bringToBack()` or `setZIndex()` to reorder your layers.

If you want one layer to always be below all others you can listen for the layer's `add` event and then bring it to the back (and bring the other to the front the same way):

```
var C300mVar1 = new L.geoJson(C300mVar1, {
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
      'add': function(){
        layer.bringToBack()
      }
    })
  }
});
```

Demo here: http://plnkr.co/edit/6c7xxWZpv3J8oTiyjG7Q